# Atom некорректно отображается результат программы

Tags: c++, atom

Проблема в том, что выводится абракадабра вместо результата. Если что установлены плагины "autocomplete-clang", "linter-clang" и "gcc compiler" для c++. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а gcc установлен?

Comment: Нет. Только что установил, проблему не решило.

Comment: атом должен ещё знать, где этот самый gcc находится. Откройте настройки gcc compiler и посмотрите, нет ли там возможности указать, где именно находится компилятор.

Comment: Спасибо что помогали. Оказалось что я просто напросто не установил MinGW на виндовс и его не было в PATH, теперь код нормально запускается через опцию "Compile and run". Однако когда запускаю через ctrl + shift + b то выскакивает ошибка No such file or directory, но это не важно.